# Passing parameter while redirecting to another route

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to 'redirect to' from one controller method to another through the route. However, I want to pass some data as well. I tried `Session::get('name')` but doesn't seem to work. This is what I tried:

```
public function before() {
   return Redirect::to('later')->with('x', 'y');
}

public function later() {
   dd( Session::get('x') ); // null
   dd( $x ) // not working
}
```

My route is like classic:

```
Route::get('/later', 'TheController@later')->middleware('auth');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can i see the route you are trying to redirect from?
Anyway, you are trying to redirect to `/later` url, but the Controller action for this URL is `Employee\EmployeeController@formAnswer` and the method, where you do the `dd` is called `later()`, so something is clearly not right. Are you sure your routes are correct?
Do the `dd(__CLASS__)` and see if you are in right controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Session::get('x')` try with `session('x')` as below.You can check for it using `if (session()->has('x'))`

```
public function later() {
   dd( session('x'));
}
```